# Windows Phone Animation going back a frame when stopped

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a mini-game as part of a larger game I'm writing for Windows phone which uses a storyboard animation to move an arrow back and forth along a bar, which the user trying to stop it in the center.

The issue I'm having is when I stop the animation, you can visibily see the arrow being animated move back a frame.

I've tried many things:

animating with keyframes and without
animating by canvas.left or translate.X
after pausing/stopping the animation, manually setting the canvas.left to the getcanvas of the arrow

With the final option not working, I wonder if the animation is actually drawing a frame ahead before it actually sets the X/Canvas.Left, and the bounce back position is the true one

Here is my animation code:

```
        double speed = .75;
        miniGameStoryboard.Stop();
        miniGameStoryboard.Children.Clear();

        // setup
        var _Translate = new TranslateTransform();
        this.MiniGame1Arrow.RenderTransform = _Translate;

        // translate (location X)
        DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames _TranslateAnimateX = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();

        System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTarget(_TranslateAnimateX, _Translate);
        System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_TranslateAnimateX, new PropertyPath(TranslateTransform.XProperty));

        _TranslateAnimateX.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame
        {
            KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)),
            Value = 0
        });

        _TranslateAnimateX.KeyFrames.Add(new LinearDoubleKeyFrame
        {
            KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(speed)),
            Value = 660
        });

        _TranslateAnimateX.AutoReverse = true;
        _TranslateAnimateX.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        _TranslateAnimateX.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd;

        miniGameStoryboard.Children.Add(_TranslateAnimateX);          
        miniGameStoryboard.Begin();
```

Comment: To test if it's a bug, have you tried the same code in a WP8 project?

Comment: I just tested in in WP7 and it has the same issue, ie if the arrow is moving left at the time, tap to pause, the arrow moves back right a few pixels